# Another version of the variable change

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ integrable and $g:[c,d] \to \mathbb{R}$ a monotonic function with $g'$ integrable.

If $g([[c,d]) \subset [a,b]$, show that $\displaystyle \int_{g(c)}^{g(d)} f(x)dx = \displaystyle \int_{c}^{d} f(g(t))g'(t)dt$

Comment: Can you assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous?

Comment: I think we can assume just $g$ continuous, once $g$ is differentiable

Comment: What is the question? What did you try?

Comment: The question is exactly that. $f$ isn't necessarily continuous, just integrable. I tried using Riemann sums but didn't work. I'm going to try some more...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume both $f$ is continuous. Suppose $F' = f$. Then, the left side is just $F(g(d)) - F(g(c))$. The right side is also
$$
\int_{c}^{d} F'(g(t))g'(t)dt = \int_{c}^{d} (F \circ g)'(t)dt = (F \circ g)(d) - (F \circ g)(c) = F(g(d)) - F(g(c))
$$

Comment: The point is assuming $f$ is only Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

After proving a lighter version of the change of variables theorem, Apostol says in his Mathematical Analysis (I'm translating from Spanish)

> There is actually a more general version of theorem $7.36$ that doesn't require the continuity of $f$ neither that of $g'$, but the proof is much more complicated. Suppose $h\in \mathscr R[c,d]$ and if $x\in [c,d]$ let $$g(x)=\int_a^x h(t)dt$$ where $a$ is some fixed point of $[c,d]$. Then if $f\in \mathscr R g([c,d])$ the integral $\displaystyle \int_c^d f(g(t))h(t)dt$ exists and $$\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(t)dt=\int_c^d f(g(t))h(t)dt$$
>
> This seems to be the most general theorem concerning change of variables in a Riemann integral. For a proof, consult the article of H.Kestelman, *Mathematical Gazette*, 45 (1961), pp. 17-23.

Comment: I think there is a slight generalization of Kestelman's Theorem which only assumes that $f$ is bounded on $g([c,d])$. A proof of this result is found here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5938v1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the fact that $g$ is absolutely continuous. Hence, by Lebesgue's Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, for any interval $[x,y] \subset [a,b]$
$$
\int_x^y g'(t)dt = g(y) - g(x)
$$
Hence, for any interval $I \subset [a,b]$
$$
\int_{g^{-1}(I)} g'(t)dt = m(I)
$$
where $m$ denotes the usual Lebesgue measure. You can rewrite this as
$$
\int_c^d \chi_I(g(t))g'(t)dt = \int_{g(c)}^{g(d)} \chi_I(t)dt
$$
(I am not sure, but I think you might have to worry about the set $\{x : g'(x) = 0\}$). Now take linear combinations of the above expression to get any step function. Since the step functions are dense in the space of all integrable functions, and both sides of the above expression are continuous, the expression is true if you replace $\chi_I$ by any integrable function.

Comment: I think the question is about Riemann integrals.

Answer (score 0):

The question I think you are asking (judging from the comment section) is given a Riemann integrable function $f$ and a monotonic differentiable function $g$ on $[c,d]$ such that $g'$ is also Riemann integrable on $[c,d]$ and $g([c,d])\subset[a,b]$ prove that $\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)dx=\int_{c}^{d}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$.

Note that since $g$ is continuous and monotonic then the image of a partition is another partition since each compact connected interval is mapped to another compact connected interval with order either preserved or reversed. Without loss of generality assume that order is preserved (the monotonic function $g$ is monotonically increasing). The case of monotonically decreasing will have a similar proof (or you could just consider $-g$).

Suppose that the theorem is true for the function $1$. This assumption implies that it holds for constant functions (since Riemann integral are linear). I will show that this implies the statement for general Riemann integrable function. Let $P$ be $c=x_{0}<...<x_{n}=d$ then $g(P)$ is $g(c)=g(x_{0})\le g(x_{1})\le...\le g(x_{n})=g(d)$. We may remove rectangles in $g(P)$ where the endpoints are equal.

$L(f,g(P))=\sum_{R\subset g(P)}m(f)vol(R)=\sum_{[g(x_{i}),g(x_{i+1})]\subset g(P)}\int_{g(x_{i})}^{g(x_{i+1})}m(f)dx=\sum_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]\subset P}\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}m(f)(g(t))g'(t)dt\le\sum_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]\subset P}\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}f(g(t))g'(t)dt=\int_{c}^{d}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$

Since the partition was arbitrary we may conclude that $\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)dx\le\int_{c}^{d}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$

With the same partition we also note the following;

$U(f,g(P))=\sum_{R\subset g(P)}M(f)vol(R)=\sum_{[g(x_{i},g(x_{i+1}]\subset g(P)}\int_{g(x_{i}}^{g(x_{i+1})}M(f)dx=\sum_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]\subset P}\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}M(f)(g(t))(g'(t))dt\ge\sum_{[x_{i},x_{i+1}]\subset P}\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}f(g(t))g'(t)dt=\int_{c}^{d}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$

Since the partition was arbitrary we may conclude that $\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)dx\ge\int_{c}^{d}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$.

Together this implies $\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}f(x)dx=\int_{c}^{d}f(g(t))g'(t)dt$. Now we just have to show that the theorem is true for the function $f=1$.

To show that the theorem is true for the function $1$ we note that following.

$\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)}1dx=g(d)-g(c)=\int_{c}^{d}g'(t)dt$

since $g'$ is assumed to be integrable.